# Mapping device memory into user process address space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While I was going through the LDD3 book, in chapter 15, (memory mapping and dma), the introduction of mmap call says:

> `mmap()` system call allows mapping of device memory directly into user process address space.

The confusion is regarding the address space. Why would device memory be mapped to user space since the kernel only takes care of the device. Why would one need to map it in user space. If the device memory is mapped in user space, why kernel manages it then? And what if the device could be used erroneously if it lies in user address space?

Please correct me if I am wrong, I am just new to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same chapter you are referring to, has the answer to your question.

> A definitive example of `mmap` usage can be seen by looking at a subset of the virtual memory areas for the X Window System server. Whenever the program reads or writes in the assigned address range, it is actually accessing the device. In the X server example, using `mmap` allows quick and easy access to the video card’s memory. **For a performance-critical application like this, direct access makes a large difference**.
>
> ...
>
> Another typical example is a program controlling a PCI device. Most PCI peripherals map their control registers to a memory address, and a **high-performance application might prefer to have direct access to the registers** instead of repeatedly having to call `ioctl` to get its work
>   done.

But you are correct that usually kernel drivers handle devices without revealing device memory to user space:

> As you might suspect, **not every device lends itself to the `mmap` abstraction**; it makes no sense, for instance, for serial ports and other stream-oriented devices. Another limitation of `mmap` is that mapping is `PAGE_SIZE` grained.

In the end, it all depends on how you want your device to be used from user space:

- which interfaces you want to provide from driver to user space
- what are performance requirements

Usually you hide device memory from user, but sometimes it's needed to give user a direct access to device memory (when alternative is bad performance or ugly interface). Only you, as an engineer, can decide which way is the best, in each particular case.

Answer (score 1):

There are few usages I can think of:

- user mode drivers - in this case kernel driver is only posing as a stub: for mapping memory to user space, passing interrupts, etc. (this is common for proprietary drivers).
- some user space application is filling or reading DMA buffers directly, to avoid copying them between user space and kernel space.

Regards,

Mateusz.